# Запуск job по времени в Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция

Есть автотесты на python в репозитории `Gitlab`. Нужна необходимость запуска автотестов по времени: раз в час например.

Знаю, что в `Jenkins` есть такая возможность, но по требованию организации, должен быть только `Gitlab`.

Есть какие то варианты `pipeline`? Или что то надо еще подключить. 
Запуск не триггерами - на push/merge, а именно по времени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это штатная возможность *GitLab CI/CD* называется **Schedules**, вот ссылка на [документацию](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html).